# ActiveRecord producing different queries for the same conditions (a join in controller, a where in model)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to improve my ruby on rails coding skills as I am not satisfied with them. In this imaginary short application I have a Product table and a Variant table. A variant belongs to a product and a product has many variants(a variant contains the price of the products and each variant has its own price thus a product can have multiple prices). A variant can be active(if there is quantity left) or inactive( if there is no quantity of that product left in that variant.
In the index action I want to display all the products with active variants with their lowest prices :

```
def index
    @display = []
    @products = Product.includes(:variants).where("variants.is_active" => true).order("variants.price")

    @products.each do |product|
      @children = product.variants.first
      if @children.present?
        @display << {
                      id: product.id,
                      title: product.title,
                      price:  @children.price,
                      quantity:  @children.quantity,
                      variant_id:  @children.id
                    }
      end
    end
    @display = Kaminari.paginate_array(@display).page(params[:page])  
  end
```

This is how my index action currently looks like.

```
@products = Product.includes(:variants).where("variants.is_active" => true).order("variants.price") as it should makes a join to retrieve the variants.
```

The resulting query looks like this:

```
SELECT "products"."id" AS t0_r0, "products"."title" AS t0_r1,  
"products"."description" AS t0_r2, "products"."created_at" AS t0_r3, 
"products"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "variants"."id" AS t1_r0,   
"variants"."is_active" AS t1_r1, "variants"."price" AS t1_r2,   
"variants"."quantity" AS t1_r3, "variants"."created_at" AS t1_r4,  
"variants"."updated_at" AS t1_r5, "variants"."product_id" AS t1_r6   
 FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "variants" ON "variants"."product_id" = "products"."id"   
 WHERE "variants"."is_active" = 't'  
 ORDER BY variants.price
```

However I find this being bad practice because I might need the same query in some other places(let's presume this). So in my product.rb I make the following relationship:

```
has_many :active_variants, -> { where(is_active: true).order(:price) }, class_name: "Variant"
```

Unlike it's counter part when I call @products = Product.includes(:active_variants) it generates an sql query in which the tables are joined in the where clause instead of a join clause like this:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  
SELECT "variants".* FROM "variants" 
WHERE   "variants"."is_active" = 't' AND "variants"."product_id" 
IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,   26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,  .... etc)
```

Why doesn't it make a sql with join as its counterpart makes and how can I enforce the join with active_variants ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the answer here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Read the paragraph 13 and especially the subparagraph 13.2

When you use `include` without `where` clause after it then this generates a set of two queries. When you use `include` with `where` clause this generates a query which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I read and I don't know what to say . Firstly I tried has_many :active_variants, -> { where(variants: {is_active: true} ) }, class_name: "Variant". or has_many :active_variants, -> { where(is_active: true).references(:variants) }, class_name: "Variant" and all combinations of these 2 methods. (references and where, writing where(variants: => {is_active: true}) still no joins. Secondly I try to write the first SQL statement just to see the output as @products = Product.includes(:variants).where("variants.is_active = true").order("variants.price").references(:variants) and i get no column true

Comment: Do note I am using ruby 1.9.3 with rails 4.2.0 if that influences something

Comment: No, that does not influences. Have you understood why this is happening ? Is there any problem which you want to solve ?

Comment: Don't think I understood. I understood that if I want to put an sql text like .where("variants.is_active = true") I have to put references(:variants). However I can't write that because it will give me an error saying that there is no column named true. Secondly in the guide it said that only by writing references(:variants) will I be able to get an sql query with join from the includes which is totally false since I get one without references(:variants). Or at least this is what I understood from what it is written in the guide

Comment: Your request that is without JOIN gives you exactly what you want (all the products with active variants). Do you need something else ?

Comment: Yes! My question was WHY does the includes(:active_variants) doesn't do a join?

Comment: Well it didn't actually answer what I had in mind. My writing :active_variant it first selects all the active variants and then it executes the includes statement and indeed since there is no where clause (because they are actually 2 different queries not a big one as I see them) there will not be a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Saying what you said in your edit answer made me realize my logic mistake so thank you very much for taking the time, I am not sure I would have had the patience with me